# Google "Open In Cloud Shell" broken?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Did Google just break its own "Open in Cloud Shell" feature?

I'm getting this error when trying to use a cloud shell link that specifies a git repo to clone from.

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I've tried on a virgin Google account, so pretty sure it's something to do with the default Cloud Shell VM setup and not something I did on the machine. It literally stopped working from one moment to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github is [shutting down password authentication](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) in favor of token-based authentication. To avoid confusion, Open in Cloud Shell will now fail instead of prompting for username/password. To continue to use Open in Cloud Shell with repositories that require authentication, you can either:

1. Manually cache your git credentials by running a git command prior
   to Open in Cloud Shell.
2. Configure [git credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) so you are not prompted for a
   username/password.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it! I'm in fact using a token, not a password. So disabling user input altogether feels a bit harsh :(